# Real time 3d rendering navigation

Tags: c#, asp.net, joomla, 3d, real-time

I have no idea at all about the `3D Visualization` ,and i want to create an application ,the application idea depends totally on the `3D structure` .

I'll do my best to clarify my question to avoid considering it vague .

The main goal of my application is the (`navigation`) part in `3D environment` .I want to upload maps of a specific area and the application allow to guide the user to its destination.(real time 3d rendering).

The application should work on `kiosk` ,`smart phones` and on `web`.(multiple platforms).

---

The following video clarify what i want to do exactly :

[3D wayfinder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ItLWaQV_0XE)

---

Now I want to know a start point to begin `without reinventing the wheel`,if there are some frameworks should i learn about first?

I'm a`.net` developer(asp.net) and i begin to learn CMS (`Joomla`),so  it 'll be great to find `APIs or frameworks` near to this area to achieve my goal as soon as possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From requirements you specified, I would like to advice to look at [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/).

1. Unity3D will help to develop application which will work on almost all major platforms including kiosk, smart phones and on web.
2. You can develop using C# language which should be familiar to you.
3. There are number of projects which aims similar goal as rendering 3D map. There are "Google Maps for Unity" plugin and I can advise to look at [Displaying Maps in Unity3D](http://ralphbarbagallo.com/2013/02/19/displaying-maps-in-unity3d/) post.
4. Unity can be integrated to Joomla if necessary

Comment: He says he is new to 3D visualization, wants 3D visualization and navigation, and he links to a video which is about indoor navigation => he seems to have much more of a GIS problem to solve. Maybe he requires to add more detailed data like indoor CAD data, maybe he even needs to create an own indoor routing graph for navigation? He didn't say. If this is the case, he'd be reinventing much of what classic GIS solutions provide. The capabilities of mentioned plugins seem very limited in this regard.

Answer (score 6):

Another option would be to build the front-end of the app using HTML5 and do the 3D using Three.js http://threejs.org/

Your back-end could serve up the map and navigation data to the front-end and you render everything in the browser or in your HTML5 smartphone app. If you need to update information in your visualization or load a new location dynamically, this can be done with a simple AJAX call and your callback would add the new info into your Three.js scene.

Answer (score 4):

Forget about what others suggest you in regards to looking at 3D frameworks. Mapping and navigation is a complexity of it's own - 3D frameworks like unity will give you 3D. But they won't give you GIS. Depending on your requirements, you could check Micello for 2D mapping and Deep Map for mobile 3D mapping (http://www.deep-map.com/en). They also help you with creating the maps - which is something you should consider for beforementioned reasons.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [OpenCV](http://www.emgu.com) library in C# for image processing and get help from HTML5 and AJAX .

Answer (score 3):

Try X3DOM. Its a programming language that can be used in applications, web browsers, and much more. And the language is ALOT like HTML and JavaScript. In fact, you can use JavaScript and HTML to access the 3D space in X3DOM.

The website for this language is: x3dom.org